# How can I cancel the settings from previous step in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I was trying to adjust the appearance of my barplot in R. Following the advice I searched. I tried one step like:

```
par(mar=c(15, 3, 3, 1))
```

However, I found it does not answer my questions. It looks the setttings are already there. How can I set it back to default?

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: `dev.off()` will close the graphics device, and the next time you need one a new one will be create with the default `par`.

Comment: Many thanks! Works well